# no unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychains signing certificate

Tags: xcode, certificate, ios-provisioning

I'm making a second computer to develop my apps (2 with differents IOS developer accounts).

I :

- exported the certificates of the people from the keychain
- installed them on the new computer
- copy-paste the files from /Users/old/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles to /Users/new/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

And when I try to archive the app,

"no unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychains signing certificate"

Edit : I saw that I dodn't had public keys, so I've imported it thanks to terminal ([this website](http://www.arlt.eu/blog/2009/12/01/importing-iphone-keys-p12-and-pem-into-snow-leopards-keychain/))

But still the same error message !

Comment: Good luck, provisioning is the biggest pain ever. A couple of times I just gave up trying to bug fix and deleted everything related to provisioning then re did it.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm making haha thanks